# Apply a custom function row by row with break

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dataframe and i'd like to iterate a custom function row by row but until to reach a specific target, and, when the condition is satisfied, i'd like to append the result in a new column and the loop goes to the next line.

[actual scenario, note that (i) is the same for all lines and i want to do that calculation for each row](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CzbQ9.png)

Bellow is my code (i'm new on python, so, any help will be appreciated)

```
def converter(a): 
    a=df_agg_70
    for i in df_agg_70:        
        for i in range(0,10000):            
            global qtd, vlr_stop, sku,var            
            sku = a['sku']
            total = a['Qtd Vendida']
            vlr_at = a['Vlr Vendido']
            conv = (((total/i)*(a['Preco_Sell_In']).astype(int))*100)/vlr_at
            vlr_stop = ((total/i) *  (a['Preco_Sell']).astype(int))
            var = conv
            var_2 = round(var[0],0)
            qtd = (total/i)
            a['var_3'] = var[0]
            a['qtd'] = qtd[0]
            a['vlr_stop'] = vlr_stop[0]
```

i want to break the code when the variable (var) get the target and restart the calculation to another line

```
        if var[0] > 50 and var[0] < 100:
            break
        return  pd.DataFrame({"sku":sku,"qtd":qtd,"valor":vlr_stop.astype(int),"var":var})
```

the current result is only considering the first line and applying for all dataset

Comment: Can you please be a bit more specific regarding the input and desired output?

Comment: I want to compare two values (Valor_Vendido / (Qtd * Preco_Sell_In)  and the result needs to be between the targets 50 and 100, if not, i need to divide the Qtd by (i) in a range  of 0 to 10.000 until the result get the target and repeating that row by row.